Bug with knowledge.sty, argument of \@fifthoffive has an extra }
I encounter a surprising bug as soon as I try to use the knowledge package:
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    hyperref,
    notion,
]{knowledge}

\knowledge{notion}
| thing

\begin{document}
A \intro{thing} and the same \kl{thing}.
\end{document}

Is anyone able to reproduce it? Do you know how to solve this?
Here is my log:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex 2024.3.15)  30 MAY 2024 19:03
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**document.tex
(./document.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count181
\c@section=\count182
\c@subsection=\count183
\c@subsubsection=\count184
\c@paragraph=\count185
\c@subparagraph=\count186
\c@figure=\count187
\c@table=\count188
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/knowledge/knowledge.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2022-01-21 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
File: l3backend-xetex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: XeTeX

(|extractbb --version)
\c__kernel_sys_dvipdfmx_version_int=\count189
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count190
\g__color_backend_stack_int=\count191
\g__graphics_track_int=\count192
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count193
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count194
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count195
))
Package: knowledge 2022/01/12 v1.27 

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2022-01-12 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count196
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2022-01-12 L3 Experimental document command parser
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/currfile/currfile.sty
Package: currfile 2020/09/29 v0.7d Provides the file path elements of the curre
nt input file

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty
Package: filehook 2020/09/29 v0.8a Hooks for input files

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook-2020.sty
Package: filehook-2020 2020/09/29 v0.8a Hooks for input files
))
\c@currfiledepth=\count197
)
\kl_sphack_int=\count198

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen139
\Hy@linkcounter=\count199
\Hy@pagecounter=\count266

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def
File: hyperref-langpatches.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: patches for babel la
nguages
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count267

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4200.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4207.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4212.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4445.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count268

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4804.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen140

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count269
\Field@Width=\dimen141
\Fld@charsize=\dimen142
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6076.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6081.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6084.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6091.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6096.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6101.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6106.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6146.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6150.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count270
\c@Item=\count271
\c@Hfootnote=\count272
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hxetex.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hxetex.def
File: hxetex.def 2021-06-07 v7.00m Hyperref driver for XeTeX

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/stringenc/stringenc.sty
Package: stringenc 2019/11/29 v1.12 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO
)
)
\pdfm@box=\box51
\c@Hy@AnnotLevel=\count273
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count274
\Fld@listcount=\count275
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count276

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip49
)
\SC@PE.area[document].count_int=\count277
\SC@PE.area[document].nesting_int=\count278
\SC@PE.area[base].count_int=\count279
\SC@PE.area[base].nesting_int=\count280
\SC@PE.area[body].count_int=\count281
\SC@PE.area[body].nesting_int=\count282
\SC@PE.area[scope].count_int=\count283
\SC@PE.area[scope].nesting_int=\count284
\SC@PE.area[knowledge context internal].count_int=\count285
\SC@PE.area[knowledge context internal].nesting_int=\count286
\SC@PE.area[knowledge import internal].count_int=\count287
\SC@PE.area[knowledge import internal].nesting_int=\count288
\knowledge_kl_recursion_int=\count289
\knowledge_autoref_count=\count290
\kl_countuse_int=\count291
\kl_countintro_int=\count292
\kl_digest_autorefused_int=\count293
\kl_digest_autorefnointro_int=\count294
\kl_digest_autoreftwiceintro_int=\count295
\kl_digest_autorefunused_int=\count296
\kl_digest_unknownknowledge_int=\count297
\kl_digest_unknownlabel_int=\count298
\kl_hyperref_kl_nesting_count_int=\count299
\knowledge_inner_modifier_count_int=\count300
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 3486.
)
(./document.kaux)
\knowledge_kaux_iow=\write3
\openout3 = `document.kaux'.

 (./document.aux)
\openout1 = `document.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 1
3.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 13.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2021-04-02 v2.47 Cross-referencing by name of section

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count301
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 13.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 13.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 13.

(./document.out) (./document.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `document.out'.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 14.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 14.

! Argument of \@fifthoffive has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 A \intro{thing} and the same \kl{thing}
                                            .
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@fifthoffive was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14 A \intro{thing} and the same \kl{thing}
                                            .
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Argument of \@fourthoffive has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14 A \intro{thing} and the same \kl{thing}
                                            .
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@fourthoffive was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14 A \intro{thing} and the same \kl{thing}
                                            .
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \hyper@readexternallink was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.14 A \intro{thing} and the same \kl{thing}
                                            .
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
\underline  ...#1}\else $\@@underline {\hbox {#1}}
                                                  \m@th $\relax \fi 
l.14 A \intro{thing} and the same \kl{thing}
                                            .
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.

\openout3 = `document.diagnose'.

(./document.kaux) [1

] (./document.aux)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `document.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10902 strings out of 478040
 222587 string characters out of 5848826
 473742 words of memory out of 5000000
 31469 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469635 words of font info for 31 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 36 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 82i,5n,80p,270b,332s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on document.pdf (1 page).


I can reproduce the issue only if I first compile the example with TeX Live 2021 and then with TeX Live 2022. Remove the auxiliary files and retry.

I did it, and runned xelatex document.tex manually twice. At the second run, the same error occurs. Do you think that updating TeXlive would help? This was my guess (but I will be able to try this only in a few weeks)...

Sorry, but I can't reproduce the issue other than by running two different executables in sequence. Can you please add \listfiles and retry, hitting return at each error and showing here the file list you get?

Here is the output of the two runs: https://pastebin.com/nHR1tQsN. The list is at the end.

Your TeX distribution claims to be TeX Live 2022, but it isn't and it's much more like TL 2021 (where the problem indeed appears). Time to upgrade. At least to update your TeX Live.

Wow, this sounds weird... Thank you for your help! I'll try this as soon as I can.
